# Adding xy data to table data from collector in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-collector

I can easily download all the data from the collector app to my PC, but how do you add the xy (coordinates) to be included as well?

Comment: how is collector recording the XY?  If it's loaded into a feature class you should be able to load that feature class directly into ArcMap.  Can you please give a bit more info around what is recorded, and into what format?  A screenshot or two might help

Answer (score 1):

For point features there is a tool in ArcGIS for Desktop called "Add XY Coordinates".